# CPU usage of remote Machine using C#(Performance Counter)

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I am trying to find CPU usage of another remote machine using PerformanceCounter class but it is throwing an exception:

> "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network path was not found
>   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceMonitor.Init() "

It is working fine if I set my machine name in Performance Counter Object's Machinename Property.

I have set Firewall setings off on remote machine .

Here is Code:

Code is as:

public partial class Default10 : System.Web.UI.Page
{

```
private PerformanceCounter cpucounter;
private PerformanceCounter ramcounter;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     try{
    InitialiseCPUCounter();
    InitialiseRAMCounter();
    //cpucounter.NextValue();


    cpucounter.MachineName = "XXXXXXXXX";/*Remote Machine Name*/

    cpucounter.NextValue();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

   this.Label1.Text = "CPU Usage:" + Convert.ToInt32(cpucounter.NextValue()).ToString() + "%"+"<br/>";
   this.Label2.Text ="RAM Usage: " +Convert.ToInt32(ramcounter.NextValue()).ToString() + "MB<br/>";
     }
    catch(Exception ex)
     {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
  }
  private void InitialiseCPUCounter()
  {
      cpucounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total", true);
  }
  private void InitialiseRAMCounter()
  {
      ramcounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes", true);
  }

  }
```

Comment: Adding your code will probably help us better understand the problem :-)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that MachineName is correct and you have rights to access to that pc?

Comment: yeah MAchine name is correct.as MachineName is only property so where to specify access rights

Comment: Ok so I have  a customer that has this same issue.  My software is requesting the performance counter information using the IP address so DNS is irrelevant.  My software impersonates then makes the call.  Dozens of other Windows Servers work correctly but specifically Windows 10 Workstations fail with this error.  I am able to run the same monitor against Windows 10 Home Workstations and I am able to get the results.  The issue appears to be network infrastructure or Windows 10 configuration specific. Most likely the API uses a port that is blocked.  What is the port?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Got it done using WIN32_Processor(WMI) class's property LoadPercentage

Comment: Down voted because this answer did not address the question but rather gave an opinion on alternative methods to get the requested information.